# How can I periodically update single page applications with PHP/HHVM as backend in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am creating a single page application with AngularJS and I am starting to really like this way of creating web applications. I use PHP as backend language and the service is set up as a REST"ish" API.

Now I face the problem of updating stuff. Since the page is practically never refreshed, I have to do some kind of polling, or long polling do check the server if any change has been made, and then let the user know about the change through notifications.

As I understand, (I might be wrong), that it is not very efficient if I am to do checks every 10 - 30 seconds if there has been a change. I would have to check if the user is logged in with JSON Web Tokens, check the database, json encode and so on, it would be very hard on the server. And as I understand PHP is not very good with websockets. What should I do?

I need to check if the user has gotten any new messages, or new comments on posts, or other notifications. My project has completely stopped because I have lately been looking at "Go" as an alternative to PHP, and because of that reason I have lost the momentum that I had.

EDIT: A couple of things I have thought about is to only run the polls if the user has moved the mouse within 30 seconds, so that I don't need to do updates when the user is not even using the site but the site is just opened in a tab that is unused. If 1000 people have a tab opened but are not using the site, then that in my opinion is a lot of wasted resources. What do you guys think?

Comment: As long as you avoid LONG polling with PHP and you don't poll constantly, but with an interval of maybe a few seconds to a minute you should be fine with PHP (This depends on the amount of users you have of course). Long polling in PHP is bad because it uses a high amount of ressources compared to the benefits.

Comment: I've been wondering about this too, what I have found so far is a mixture between socket.io & pusher.com. But I haven't actually gotten to use them yet.

Comment: Since you work with angularJS already, then why not go fullstack and use node.js on the backend?

Comment: The reason for staying with PHP was HHVM, and the fact that I know PHP better than other server side languages, even if NodeJS is JavaScript, it is not the kind of clientside JavaScript that I am used to, if that makes sense. I find it much easier to code in PHP serverside.

Comment: have you looked at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about over-working the database, you can probably just compare counts: eg, your Angular app knows about X comments/notifications, you poll the server to check if the server has > X comments/notifications (a simple and efficient SQL count), and if it does, notify the user and make a full request for the comments/notifications, with related objects, etc.

Websockets and the like would be overkill for this type of thing, unless you're just curious to try them out.